# iOS How to fetch value "Boolean" from parse Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, fetch

I build app, in which i need to check if user verified email.
My code to fetch data:

```
  let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User");
        query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.current()!.objectId!)
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (object, error) in
            if !(error != nil) {
                let user = PFUser.current()
                let emailVerified = user!["emailVerified"] as! Bool
                print("emailVerified \(emailVerified)")
            }
        }
```

And i have error:

[image]

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

**UPDATE:**

So in my table i have value "false"
[image]

When code is running in console i receive value "true"

[image]

Comment: can you print `user`

Comment: are you getting Int from user!["emailVerified"]?

Comment: Yes i get  emailVerified = 0; Int, but i cat fetch like Int

Comment: @Andrew Please find my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement below extension as well for generic terms,

```
extension Integer {
    var boolValue: Bool { return self != 0 }
}
```

then use it like this,

```
let success = user!["emailVerified"].boolValue
```

**UPDATE**

You can do this way also,

```
let success = (user!["emailVerified"] as NSNumber).boolValue
```

another option will be like this,

```
extension Bool {    
    init(_ number: Int) {
        self.init(number as NSNumber)
    }
}
```

and get it like this,

```
let success = Bool(user!["emailVerified"] as NSNumber)
```

Try it out and let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: It's working not ideal, because in by table i have value false, but i fetch value true

Comment: What is the exact issue?

Comment: @PLL in upper i wrote, what is problem

Comment: can you print this? user!["emailVerified"], is it 0 or 1?

Comment: emailVerified = 0;

Comment: then it must be false, I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if let isVerify = user!["emailVerified"] as? NSNumber {
    let emailVerified = isVerify.boolValue
}
```

Comment: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Bool' with an argument list of type '(Any!)'